# Django: update not saving date without raising error

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view in my Django app where I want to update a queryset´s DateField. It´s quite simple, the field works fine in other views (not a model problem) and it doesn´t raise any error when running the view.

The other elements in the view are stored ok.

**The view**

```
@transaction.atomic
@login_required

def BocetoArmando(request):

    ## This part od the code works just fine

    operaciones = OperacionK.objects.filter(creador__username='this_user', estatus__id=1)
    operaciones.update(
        fecha_conf_comercial=date.today(),
        fecha_conf_admin=date.today(),
        confirmador_admin=request.user,
        estatus=EstatusOperacionK.objects.get(estatus__icontains="Armando"))

    ## This part of the code does not save anything, 
    ## although it works perfectly in the shell

    lista = [x.id for x in operaciones]
    pedidos = PedidosK.objects.filter(comprobante__in=lista)
    pedidos.update(fecha_conf_comercial=date.today())

    for pedido in pedidos:
        producto = ProductosBase.objects.get(pk=pedido.producto.id)
        producto.existencias = producto.existencias - pedido.uds
        producto.existencias_bloqueada = producto.existencias_bloqueada - pedido.uds
        producto.save(update_fields={'existencias', 'existencias_bloqueada'})

    return DispatchManager(request)
```

I tried both options with the same result:

```
pedidos.update(fecha_conf_comercial=datetime.datetime.today())


pedidos.update(fecha_conf_comercial=date.today())
```

If I run everything in Django´s shell it´s updated correctly.

This is part of a big app that handles this datefield without any problems in the rest of the views. I can´t figure out what is happening here.

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `print(pedidos.count())` give you in the view?

Comment: Are you sure `pedidos` is not an empty queryset in your view ?

Comment: The 'pedidos' is not empty

Comment: I tryied all the code in the server´s shell and it works fine. Very crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Everything worked fine in the shell and not in the view due to lazziness of the querys and specially with `@transaction.atomic`.

When the `lista` was made the `operaciones` queryset was actualy empty beacuse I updated it before.

I just needed to change the order of the process and leave this part of the code to the end.

```
operaciones.update(
    fecha_conf_comercial=date.today(),
    fecha_conf_admin=date.today(),
    confirmador_admin=request.user,
    estatus=EstatusOperacionK.objects.get(estatus__icontains="Armando"))
```

Thanks to everyone who dedicated some time to this.